# pinch to zoom gesture

Tags: swift, label, pinchzoom

I made this code to allow the user to pinch on a text to Zoom In or Out.
Is it possible to put a minRange and a maxRange? How can I do it.
Another question: is it possible to return to the default zoom after a double click? Thanks a lot.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureView()
        pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(pinchText(sender:)))
        tv_testoCanzone.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        let range = NSMakeRange(tv_testoCanzone.text.count - 1, 0)
        tv_testoCanzone.scrollRangeToVisible(range)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func pinchText(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        var pointSize = tv_testoCanzone.font?.pointSize
        pointSize = ((sender.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize!;
        tv_testoCanzone.font = UIFont( name: "arial", size: (pointSize)!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably putting a lower and upper limit on the `pointSize` variable will work:

```
@objc func pinchText(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    var pointSize = tv_testoCanzone.font?.pointSize
    pointSize = ((sender.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize!;

    let maxZoom = <some number>
    let minZoon = <some number>
    if pointSize > maxZoom {
        pointSize = maxZoom
    }
    if pointSize < minZoom {
        pointSize = minZoom
    }

    tv_testoCanzone.font = UIFont( name: "arial", size: (pointSize)!)
}
```

Have you considered using a [`UIScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) or [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview) (which is itself a `UIScrollView`)? They have these gestures worked out for you.